# Getting lots of controller calls with Xamarin Azure Pullasync

Tags: azure, xamarin, controller

We are using xamarin forms to create an Azure backed mobile app. We are using offline data sync to allow offline data storage and processing. This is all hooked up as per the many walkthroughs on the web and all seems to be working fine.

One of our tables contains ~5000 rows which is causing us a few issues. When you do the initial sync with the app using the code;

```
this.listTable = client.GetSyncTable<Entities.List>();
await this.listTable.PullAsync("allLists", listTable.CreateQuery());
```

the azure .NET service seems to get his thousands of times. I have debugged the services' GetAllList() method on azure - containing the code;

```
public IQueryable<List> GetAllList()
{
    return Query(); 
}
```

and the breakpoint get’s hit a lot. I have checked out what Query() is returning and it looks to be returning the whole dataset (~5000 rows) as I would expect.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong to have it called so many times? It looks to be returning the whole dataset for maybe each row in the dataset - causing the sync to be very slow.

I stepped through the controller process when debugging and it doesn’t just look to be calling the GetAllList() method loads of times, it initialises the controller then calls the GetAllList method over and over again.

I’m sure I’ve set something up incorrectly and it’s a simple mistake as I can’t believe this is by design, but can’t for the life of me spot what I have done wrong :(

Any help would be very welcome!

Thanks,
Al.

Comment: Are there any scheduled configuration to run the sync? Do you have a git hub repo ?

Comment: I don’t have a git hub repo unfortunately - it’s being made for our company on site using TFS for source control. The sync is run when the app starts.

Comment: I have a class in my PCL that contains the MobileServiceClient, the sync tables, etc. and I have a SyncAsync task in there. I call this when the app starts up to sync all of my offline tables.The class was created by Azure when I created the mobile app using the quickstart template - very similar to what can be seen in this webpage - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/sync/azure-mobile-apps/

Comment: This is one deep dive mentioning the implementation. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/04/07/deep-dive-on-the-offline-support-in-the-managed-client-sdk/      var localTable = client.GetSyncTable<TodoItem>();
var query = localTable.Where(t => !t.Complete);
await localTable.PullAsync(query);
 
var localItems = await localTable
    .Select(i => i.Text)
    .ToListAsync();
AddToDebug("Items from the server (in the local table): {0}", string.Join(", ", localItems));

Comment: Sorted it - kind of. Turns out the pagesize for the requests is 50 by default. This results in loads of calls to the service to the number of rows I was calling taking loads of time. I can up the MaxPageSize on the client and the PageSize on the service and it is significantly quicker. Came across the suggestions here for reference - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff5b6ba7-76c7-42fe-847d-9898256e3249/problem-syncing-large-table?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the pagesize for the requests is 50 by default. This results in loads of calls to the service to the number of rows I was calling taking loads of time.

I can up the MaxPageSize on the client and the PageSize on the service and it is significantly quicker.

Came across the suggestions here for reference - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff5b6ba7-76c7-42fe-847d-9898256e3249/problem-syncing-large-table?forum=azuremobile

There are, of course things that need to be taken into account when upping this value - but at least it explains what was happening.